# Как объяснить запятую?

Tags: пунктуация

...которая всё ещё шла в гору, хотя не так уж круто" Почему запятая перед хотя? "хотя не так уж круто" - это другое простое предложение? Где тогда грамматическая основа?

Answer (score 2):

..которая всё ещё шла в гору, хотя не так уж круто. Шла куда?как?-в гору, хотя (но) не ...круто.- можно разобрать как предложение с однородными обстоятельствами, запятая перед противительным союзом.

Возможно прочитать  с присоединит. интонацией, тогда запятая будет при присоединительной конструкции.

Answer (score 2):

Да, здесь используется сложное предложение, придаточное уступки - неполное предложение, текст которого мы восполняем из предыдущего контекста(хотя не так уж круто шла в гору, или - которая не так уж и круто шла в гору), тогда и появляется сказуемое или полностью вся грамматическая основа.

Answer (score 1):

Часть "хотя не так уж круто" является предложением неполным. Основа "которая шла" из первого предложения подразумевается и во втором: "хотя (которая шла) не так уж круто"

Comment: А Вы попробуйте всё это подставить:(дорога),которая всё ещё шла в гору, хотя которая шла не так уж круто - ерунда получается. Было бы неполное предложение в таком случае:(дорога),которая всё ещё шла в гору, хотя шла не так уж круто. А в данном виде не два придаточных, а одно, осложнённое или однородными членами, или присоединительной конструкцией. Уж это поверьте учителю с 33-летним стажем работы.

Comment: Вот примеры на однородные члены с союзом хотя (я более склоняюсь к однор.чл.):
Сквозь невеселую, хотя свежую улыбку увядающей природы, казалось, прокрадывался унылый страх недалекой зимы. Это было громко, хотя уже не так весело. Он пел по-русски разухабисто,хотя не так уж и правильно. По-моему, примеры похожи на наш случай.
   http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook089/01/part-031.htm